# How to clear QLineEdit without triggering signal

Tags: python, pyqt

`QLineEdit` triggers a signal on `.clear()` or `.setText()` method.
So every time those methods are used to stop LineEdit from emitting the signal I need to `.blockSignals(True)` and then `.blockSignals(False)`.
I wonder if there is a way around it?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui    
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__()
        self.setText('Some Text')
        self.textChanged.connect(self.printMessage)
        self.show()
    def printMessage(self):
        print 'Triggered!'

line=LineEdit()
line.clear()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered `QLineEdit::textEdited`? It doesn't emit signals when the text is changed programatically.

Comment: Is there any way to say which method emits signal and which doesn't without going to docs?

Comment: @Sputnix I guess not. There is no alternative to check the docs regularly for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is probably better, but maybe some scenarios this solution is also useful:

```py
def function_that_doesnt_trigger_textchanged(self):
    self.in_this_function = True
    self.textbox.change_text()
    self.in_this_function = False

def on_text_changed(self):
    if self.in_this_function:
        return
    do_thing_on_text_changed()
```